# An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled [Rails DB error]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

To provide some background: I've been building out a personal blog and as with any other blog it requires User authentication (or atleast one User) to be in the database. So, in development I created a user right from the rails console which worked.

However, in production I needed an authentication system in order to create posts. So what I did was attempt to install devise to handle just that, albeit I am getting the error shown below.

I know the issue has to do with already having a pre-existing user table in my DB, but the problem is - when trying to run rake db:migrate to drop the table I get an error, which ultimately, has me at a stand-still.

Please advise.

github: https://github.com/Apane/Blogit_blog

```
rake db:migrate
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "encrypted_password" varchar(128) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "password_salt" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "reset_password_token" varchar(255), "remember_token" varchar(255), "remember_created_at" datetime, "sign_in_count" integer DEFAULT 0, "current_sign_in_at" datetime, "last_sign_in_at" datetime, "current_sign_in_ip" varchar(255), "last_sign_in_ip" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL) /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:278:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:278:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:170:in `create_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:334:in `method_missing'
/Users/user/Sites/personal_blog/personal_blog/db/migrate/20130528200110_devise_create_users.rb:3:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that in the error it states:

```
rake db:migrate
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:users
```

So whats happening I believe is that your trying to migrate a `users` table that is already currently there. Also I noticed that you are using devise. Did you run the following commands:

```
rails g devise:install

rails g devise user

rake db:migrate
```

You should also compare your schema.rb version with your db/migrate/*.rb files.

**Update**

Are you sure you are connecting to the same database. Because I just noticed that you said

> in development I created a user right from the rails console which worked.

But in `production` you are having problems. It seems to me that you may not be connecting to the same DB. Also word of advice don't use SQLite3 for production.

Please check what database you are connecting to for which environment. Good practice if you are releasing an application on Heroku. You may notice this uses Postgres. Good practice is to use the same database for development and production.

Once you find out which database you are connecting to and what it is I am certain this could be the issue.

Further if you are trying to migrate in production or anything like that you could use the following: `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` this will execute the migrate for the production environment

Comment: Yes - you are correct, but please read the initial post for more insight. Ultimately, the main issue is that every time I run rake db:migrate to drop the former user table - I get the above error.

Comment: @TonyP - reate_users migration (APP_ROOT/db/migrate/..), add drop_table :users right before create_table :users and run rake db:migrate. It will remove the users table before recreating it. You can remove that line of code after running this migration so it doesn't give you errors later on.

Comment: @TonyP For your former table how did you get rid of it. Did you just simply delete it from the migration directory.

Comment: Very strange but it's having trouble finding the :users table in order to drop it. e.g. SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: DROP TABLE "users"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'

Comment: @TonyP check my update to my answer. You may need to check a few things

Answer (score 1):

For your problem

> SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "encrypted_password" varchar(128) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "password_salt" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "reset_password_token" varchar(255), "remember_token" varchar(255), "remember_created_at" datetime, "sign_in_count" integer DEFAULT 0, "current_sign_in_at" datetime, "last_sign_in_at" datetime, "current_sign_in_ip" varchar(255), "last_sign_in_ip" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)

Maybe you can check your schema_migrations version in your database.  If you found your users table version number(I mean in your db/migrate/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_devise_create_users.rb file, and xxxxxxxxxxxxxx is your version number) is behind the version in the table and your users table is already exist, you can add users table version number by yourself for skipping the creating operation.